# Pick out part of a url with javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following url:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysIzPF3BfpQ&feature=rec-LGOUT-exp_stronger_r2-2r-3-HM
or
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysIzPF3BfpQ

How can I pick out just the 11 character string, ysIzPF3BfpQ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str.match(/v=(.*?)(&|$)/)[1];
```

It looks for a `v=`, then the *shortest* string of characters `(.*?)`, followed by either a `&` or the end of the string. The `[1]` retrieves the first grouping, giving: `ysIzPF3BfpQ`.

Comment: That's what I was going for. Much nicer and simpler than mine.

Comment: Can be simplified (and sped up) even more: `str.match(/v=([^&]+))[1];`

Answer (score 1):

To get the first capture group `()` from the URL that matches `v=***********`:

```
url.match(/v=(.{11})/)[1]
```

Comment: What if the url is just: youtube.com/watch?v=ysIzPF3BfpQ ?

Comment: Fixed it to just get the next 11 characters, so you have to assume that v= will never be blank.